# How to set multiple Starting points for autoNumber field in an access table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working on a MS access based tasks list where all teams have been assigned with a series to use as unique ID. ie, team A will number their tasks from 100 to 199, then team B will use series 200 to 299 ad so on. whenever they perform a task they will use a macro to get next available number in their respective series.

Now I have created the table but unable to find a way to return the next incremental number from each teams series. Is there any way to get this done? I want to achieve this in a single table.

I'm using Access 2016 and VBA.

Comment: You won't be able to use an autonumber field for that.  You'll have to run a query to count the entries or use DCOUNT when a new record is added.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use autonumber. You have to manually assign the ID.

To get the next ID per group:

```
NextIDForGroup = Nz(DMax("IDFieldName","TableName","IDFieldName >= " & [StartingPointForGroup] & " AND IDFieldName < " & [StartingPointForGroup]+[IntervalBetweenGroups]),[StartingPointForGroup] - 1) + 1
```

If you are assured that each group ahs at least one exiting record it can ve simplified to:

```
NextIDForGroup = DMax("IDFieldName","TableName","IDFieldName >= " & [StartingPointForGroup] & " AND IDFieldName < " & [StartingPointForGroup]+[IntervalBetweenGroups]) + 1
```

I assume you will pick your starting IDs properly so there is no chance for overlap.

Comment: You can automatically assign the IDs using data macros. However, you can't use a `DMax` in there.